# Using a motor to provide resistance for string potentiometer

Tags: motor, potentiometer

I have a string potentiometer that I want to attach to a handle. As an example, if the user does a bicep curl, the string pot will measure speed of the movement. The string pot I have, I assume, has a spring inside to provide the resistance to recoil the string after the curl.

I am wondering if there is a way to attach a motor, or other device, to the string pot to provide resistance to the wire when pulled. I would hope to build a user interface to control how much resistance is applied so one user can set the resistance to 5kg, then I can change it to 10kg for the next user.

Is this possible or is there a better set of components to achieve this goal?

Thank you!

Comment: You would not normally use the string pot's own string to provide "resistance" -- it would eventually stretch (or break) and lose accuracy. Instead, use a separate cable to provide the resistance and run the string pot string in parallel with that cable, with only the internal spring putting tension on it. The alternative would be to simply put a shaft encoder on your resistance motor and forget about the string pot altogether.

Answer (score 1):

Using a motor as a fixed torque load is possible; supplying a current to a motor results in torque, which you could exercise against.  Standard motors have a "cogging torque" which makes the motor torque vary as the magnets are more or less aligned, so you would need to accurately know the rotor position to apply the right current to the correct phases for smooth torque.

There is a device called a hysteresis brake that would be easier to design around.  You only have to apply a direct current to these devices to produce a known torque.  You can usually find surplus ones at a reasonable cost if you want to experiment.  But this would act as a brake and would not provide any opposing torque when stationary, so it may not be what you need.

Keep in mind that whatever power you can generate with your biceps must be dissipated as heat in the brake, but this is common to all exercise equipment that use brakes, such as stationary bikes.